# A C++ program - With a class called platypus (Error of no instance constructor)

Tags: c++

I have created a program in C++ about a class called Platypus. This program shows the characteristics of a platypus. However, I have encountered an error in which it says "No instance of constructor '...' matches the argument list" for a char that I have in my Explicit value Constructor. I have tried changing the double-quotes into single quotes but it still doesn't work. Additionally, I have another char within this constructor and used double quotes and it does not show any signs of error.

I would appreciate any help I can get to fix this problem, Thank you!

**Platypus Header File**

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    #ifndef PLATYPUS_H
    #define PLATYPUS_H

    class Platypus
    {
    public:

        //Class constructors
        //Default Constructor
        Platypus();
        //Explicit value Constructor
        Platypus(char initGender, float initWeight, 
            short initAge, char initName,
            bool initAlive, bool initMutant);

        //Accessors
        char getGender() const;
        float getWeight() const;
        unsigned short getAge() const;
        char getName() const;


        //Input and Output
        //Display the Platypus' attributes
        void print(ostream &out) const;



    private:
        //Data members
        char gender;
        float weight;
        short age;
        char name;
        bool alive,
            mutant;
    };


    #endif
```

**Platypus cpp file**

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    #include "platypus.h"

    //Definition of Default Constructor
    Platypus::Platypus()
        : alive(false)
    {
    }

    //Definition of explicit-value Constructor
    Platypus::Platypus(char initGender, float initWeight, 
        short initAge, char initName, bool initAlive = true,
        bool initMutant = false)
    {
        //Check Class invariant
        gender = initGender;
        weight = initWeight;
        age = initAge;
        name = initName;
        alive = initAlive;
        mutant = initMutant;
    }

    //Definition of getGender
    char Platypus::getGender() const
    {
        return gender;
    }

    //Definition of getWeight
    float Platypus::getWeight() const
    {
        return weight;
    }

    //Definition of getAge
    unsigned short Platypus::getAge() const
    {
        return age;
    }

    //Definition of getName
    char Platypus::getName() const
    {
        return name;
    }

    //Definition of Display function
    void Platypus::print(ostream & out) const
    {
        out << "Gender: " << gender << endl;
        out << "Weight: " << weight << endl;
        out << "Age: " << age << endl;
        out << "Name: " << name << endl;

        if (alive == 1)
        {
            out << "Alive: YES" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            out << "Alive: NO" << endl;
        }

        if (mutant == 0)
        {
            out << "Mutant: YES" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            out << "Mutant: NO" << endl;
        }
    }
```

**Main**

```
    #include "platypus.h"
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        cout << "\n*Hello and welcome to the Class called Platypus*\n" <<         endl;
        cout << "This program will display the characteristics of a platypus." << endl;

        Platypus platypus1,
            platypus2;

        Platypus platypus1('M', 10.0, 6, "N", true, true); //This is where I have the error with the letter "M". I used double quotes and single quotes and it is still not working.

        platypus1.print();

        cout << "\n";
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The `"N"` with double quotes that you pass to the constructor is not a `char`. It will appear as a `const char *`. You must use `'N'` with single quotes to pass a char.

Comment: "I have tried changing the double-quotes into single quotes but it still doesn't work." - Apparently, they've already tried that. It looks like there're two errors in one here...

Comment: You also declare `platypus1` twice. Delete the first one. Also, if you want a string for `name`, use `std::string`. Also, you need to pass a parameter to print (`platypus1.print(cout);`). But you probably want to override `operator<<`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to changing `Platypus platypus1('M', 10.0, 6, "N", true, true);` to `Platypus platypus1('M', 10.0, 6, 'N', true, true);`, you also need to remove the first `Platypus platypus1` statement. You should only construct `platypus1` once.